# Jquery Datatable export to excel

Tags: jquery, datatable, export-to-excel

I have used export to excel functionality of Jquery. Its working fine. I am able to see all the columns with proper data. In the excel sheet i am having one date columns in that the date values are coming as belows

1/02/2014

3/05/2014

.#######

.#######

7/07/2014

But when i expand the excel column i am able to see the date in below format(there are some spaces before the dates)

1/02/2014

3/05/2014

```
  4/05/2014 

  7/05/2014
```

7/07/2014

So my question is that, is there any way to align the text in excel sheet using JQuery datatable.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Excel shows ######## when the column is too narrow to display a number (dates are numbers). It seems that some html formatting carries over to Excel.

Since Excel already shows the dates correctly, you can remove any formatting from the column (Home ribbon > Clear Formats and re-apply your favorite date format.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Teylyn for quick reply. Its fine the suggestion you have given. But i am still thinking why this issue is not coming on all the date values. If you see on my query some of the dates are getting printed properly. If this the case what you are telling then it should be applied on every value of that column. Please suggest.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the datatable.